# Are any of the columns in the Tableau Server sites or users customizable?

Tags: tableau-api

I haven't come across any documentation provided by Tableau in asking this question but I'd like to ask if anyone knows whether the info columns in the Sites or Users section are customizable for anyone with Server Administrator privileges. Mainly these columns show site/user metrics but I'm not sure if you can add your own columns to that list to track your own metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Even Admins do not have the ability to add/sort/change columns on these pages (or any other pages, I believe.)

You can always make this suggestion on the [Tableau Ideas Forum](https://community.tableau.com/community/ideas/content) though. Others can vote your idea up and Tableau will see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom admin views of information stored in the Tableau server repository. See this link. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/adminview_postgres.htm

You could also use the server's Rest API to query information and display however you like. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api.htm

If you're working in Python, there is an open source library that makes using the Rest API more convenient
https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python